# macos _tkinter TclError: can't find package Tix

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tix

In Macos,when I compile a python program, it appears:
_tkinter TclError: can't find package Tix

How to reslove it ?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780141/tkinter-tclerror-cant-find-package-tix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_tkinter TclError: can't find package Tix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780141/tkinter-tclerror-cant-find-package-tix)

Answer (score 0):

This is my question, It cost my whole days, I just want to record it or help others.

Download software

1. Download xQuartz:
   [download xQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/)
2. Download Tcl 8.5 and Tk 8.5

   (1) weblink goto:[Tcl Tk download link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/)

   (2) in the bottom of the webpage,choose which version you want.

   ```
   I choose the tcl8519-src.zip and the tk8519-src.zip
   ```

   (3) remember: need download the same verion.
3. Down Tix 8.4, the version could be different to the tcl/tk.

   The weblink is:
   [Tix download](http://tix.sourceforge.net/download.shtml)

*****Prepare******

1. you could got: XQuartz-2.8.1.dmg, just open and install it with default choice.
2. create a dir named "src", suggest not change the "src" dir name.
3. move all three zip file to the src dir.
4. double click ,just unzip all the three file.

******Compile******

1. compile tcl

   [ Tips: not need make install ]

   ```
   cd /Users/lee/tcltktix/src/tcl8.5.19/macosx/
   ./configure --enable-threads --enable-symbols --enable-shared --enable-framework --enable-64bit
   make
   ```
2. compile tx, and install it

[IMPORTANT] --with-tcl=**** replace your real dir.

the last char of "dir--with-tcl", must be "/"

```
   cd /Users/lee/tcltktix/src/tk8.5.19/macosx/
   ./configure --enable-threads --enable-symbols --enable-shared --enable-framework --enable-aqua  --with-tcl=/Users/lee/tcltktix/src/tcl8.5.19/macosx/
   make
   sudo make install
```

3. compile Tix and install it

[IMPORTANT] --with-tcl=**** --with-tk=**** replace your real dir.

the last char of "dir--with-**", must be "/"

```
   cd /Users/lee/tcltktix/src/Tix8.4.3
   ./configure --enable-threads --enable-shared --enable-framework LDFLAGS="-L/usr/X11/lib" --with-tcl=/Users/lee/tcltktix/src/tcl8.5.19/macosx/  --with-tk=/Users/lee/tcltktix/src/tk8.5.19/macosx/
   make
   sudo make install
```

NOW the Tix has been installed.

*****Question*****

1. If receieve could not find the tclConfig.h:

   check the dir in your compile configure order set, whether if have the "/" is the last char?

2.If you mac feedback a fatal error: ‘X11/Xlib.h’ file not found during compile, you should link the file:

```
ln -s /opt/X11/include/X11 /usr/local/include/X11
```

******Check******

```
   MacBook-Air-1531:~ lee$ python3
   Python 3.7.5 (v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 14 2019, 18:49:57)
   [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> from tkinter import tix
   >>> 
   >>> root = tix.Tk()
   >>>
```

Now, a window with title "tix" appeared.

congratulation!!!