# Python Error using Tkinter tix when create exe or msi with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I'm trying to make with Python an EXE/MSI of my script, but in my script I use the library **tkinter.tix** i use that to create a Balloon tooltip. If i execute the script with the IDLE runs very well, but if i try to make an EXE(auto-py-to-exe) or MSI(cx_Freeze), shows me an error.

I import the module like this:

```
from tkinter.tix import *
```

I attach the error in picture.

[image: Tix Error]

I appreciate you can help me!!! Thanks...

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093591/pyinstaller-cant-find-package-tix) may help.

Comment: there are many similar questions on Stackoverflow and always is the same problem: Python wasn't created to build `.exe` and tools like `PyInstalle`, `cx_Freeze`, etc. may have problem to find all needed Python modules and C/C++ libraries - and then you have to add them manually to project. `PyInstaller` has special file `.spec` for this. In `PyInstaller` documentation you can find pages `"Using Spec File"` and `"What to do when something goes wrong"`

Comment: your error shows that it can't filnd C/C++ library `libtix.8.1.8.3.so` or similar (because `.so` means library for `Linux`) - so you have to add this manually to project. Details you have to find in documentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the `tix` folder in the Python installed folder into the distributed folder as well.

Below is a sample `setup.py` when `cx_Freeze` is used:

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# change to the correct path for the tix folder in your system
include_files = [(r'C:\Python38\tcl\tix8.4.3', r'lib\tkinter\tix8.4.3')]

build_exe_options = {
    'include_files': include_files,
}

bdist_msi_options = {}

setup(
    name='Demo',
    version='0.1',
    options = {
        'build_exe': build_exe_options,
        'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options,
    },
    executables=[Executable('tix-demo.py', base='Win32GUI')],
)
```

Then build the MSI by executing the following command:

```sh
python3 setup.py bdist_msi
```